# flask_restful array-like arguments in GET API

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I'm developing REST APIs with flask_restful. I can parse arguments using parser.parse_args(). I would like my requests appears like this, based on the selection of items in client application:

/api/select-brand/brand[0]=123&brand[1]=128

However, selection of items could grow and requested API could be like this:

/api/select-brand/brand[0]=123&brand[1]=128&brand[2]=54&brand[3]=14

With only two arguments, I have the following in my code:

```
class SelectBrand(Resource):
    def get(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('brand1')
        parser.add_argument('brand2')
        data = parser.parse_args()
```

However, I don't know how to parse arguments when GET request parameters are like a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you are looking for `append` argument:

```
parser.add_argument('brand', action='append')
```

In this case when you parse the arguments `brand` will be a list.

But this requires to update the URL. See full example in [the docs](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/reqparse.html#multiple-values-lists).

Comment: That works fine. However, with append argument my request looks like this:
/api/select-brand/brand=123&brand=128. I think it's the way Flask-RESTful handles append arguments.